# jQuery to multi-select all values if first option is selected

Tags: c#, jquery

If the first option 'All' is selected then i want to ensure all remaining options are checked. If the first option 'All' is unchecked then i want to ensure all remaining options are unchecked.

It seems to be selecting the values, but does not check the options on the front end.

Codeply example given: https://www.codeply.com/go/ExFJtHShnF

Jquery code I have written - not working as it should

```
$("#basic").change(function () {   
    if ( $("#basic option:first").prop('selected') ) {
        $('#basic option').prop('selected', true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make this work you need to use a delegated `change` event handler as the content of the dropdown is dynamically created.

Then you can simply call `selectAll` or `deselctAll` based on the `checked` property of the first box, like this:

```js
$('#basic').multiselect({
  templates: {
    li: '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><label class="pl-2"></label></a></li>'
  }
});

$(document).on('change', '.multiselect-container :checkbox:first', function() {
  $('#basic').multiselect(this.checked ? 'selectAll' : 'deselectAll').multiselect('refresh');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.13.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <br /><br />
  <select class="custom-select" id="basic" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="0">All</option>
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: How would you as a default in jquery select all options on document ready?

Comment: Call this after defining the multiselect: `$('.multiselect-container :checkbox').prop('checked', true)`